# Flash player IE7 BitmapData send to server with amfphp

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, amfphp

Does anybody experienced this kind of fault.

So i have some kind of imageuploader.

It fetches an image, grabs the bitmap data from it. convert that with a jpgencoder to a bytearray, send that bytearray to a server with amfphp and in php save that as a jpg on the server.

So this works great in FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera ( Mac & Windows )
But when i try it on IE7. It works for the first time but when i try it another time it seems to send the first picture(bytearray) back to the server. (if i compare the bytearray code that charles catches up)

anybody experienced this kind of bug? problem? is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. IE7 caching problem.

?Math.random();

does a lot :)

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that the server has a problem in that it's not returning proper caching headers.  See http://www.enhanceie.com/redir/?id=httpperf for an explanation of how HTTP caching works.